# Where should i save my images that user uploads? java web application

Tags: java, web-applications

I am saving the image at this location :-

```
private static String photoGalleryPath = "/Common/PhotoGallery/";
```

I save the image at `context.getRealPath(photoGalleryPath)`

Everything works fine, but when i clean and build my project. The whole folder of PhotoGallery gets deleted. This looks very funny to me :). Why does it delete my whole folder everytime? And what more should i do to tell the extra smart Glassfish to not to delete my folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should not be storing data within your servlet's webContent directory because (as you observe) redeployment of the WAR may blow it away.

Instead, create a directory somewhere else to hold the images; e.g. `/var/yourProject/PhotoGallery/` Alternatively save the images in some kind of database / filestore.

Comment: Ok! but if i store it that way, what path should i give to h:graphicImage? because it only expects relative path from our web application. Please help me i am beginner :(

What does var mean? do you mean var folder of Ubuntu? How do i give this path to my h:graphicImage?

Comment: "/var/yourProject/PhotoGallery/" is an example pathname.  Replace it with the (absolute) pathname of the directory where you want to store the images.